# Can't render validations errors in form partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I try to render validation errors in a form partial.

I have :

```
resas/_form.html.erb

<%= form_for ([@resa, Resa.new]) do |f| %>
<% if @resa.errors.any? %>
     <% @resa.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
   <h3><%= msg %></h3>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
 ...
<div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

I dislay this form in the index view, through another partial called `_agenda` :

```
resas/index.html.erb

<%= render "shared/agenda" %>


shared/_agenda.html.erb

<%= render "resas/form" %>
```

In the controller :

```
def create
    @resa = Resa.new(params[:resa])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @resa.save
        format.html { redirect_to resas_path, notice: 'Resa was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @resa, status: :created, location: @resa }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to resas_path }
        format.json { render json: @resa.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I would like to redirect to the index action, and render validation errors, but I can't.
I have :

```
NoMethodError in Resas#index

undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
```

how could I do ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can render to index action instead redirect in else part

Comment: You will get the object errors in index view also. Its like same when we save object in create action and render to new if error comes